# Converting working system to a chrome App

Tags: events, callback, google-chrome-app, listeners

After hitting some of the limitations in a standard browser based application, I decided to convert it to a chrome App that doesn't use the browser.

Below are all the relevant parts. The problem I'm trying to solve is to add a load listener for a button that was working in the browser and doesn't work under the app architecture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>POS Data Entry Sheet</title>
<link href="./POS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./POS.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.underDevelopment.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.generateTable.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.menu.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.portion.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.formula.js"></script>
<script src="./POS.dialog.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
   addLoadListener(addHandlerForLoginButton);
</script>

<section id="login">
<h1>Please login:</h1>

<p>
   <label>User ID:</label><input type="text" id="userID">
   <label>Password:</label><input type="password" id="password">
   <button type="submit" id="loginButton">Login</button>
</p>
</section>

<div id="main"></div>  <!--Everything gets attached to this div.-->

</body>
</html>
```

Everything above works via the browser. 
I created the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Point of Sale System",
  "description": "Dual currency Point of Sale System",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["POS.dialog.js",
                  "POS.formula.js",
                  "POS.generateTable.js",
                  "POS.js",
                  "POS.menu.js",
                  "POS.portion.js",
                  "POS.underDevelopment.js",
                  "background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my first attempt at the background.js
It brings up the rudimentary page, but the in line script wasn't working.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
   chrome.app.window.create('POS.html', {
      'bounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
      }
   });
});
```

So, I commented out the inline script and attempted to add a callback function
This also doesn't work. No event listeners are recorded as per the debug tool.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
   chrome.app.window.create('POS.html', {
      'bounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
      }
   }, function(win) {win.addEventListener('load', addHandlerForLoginButton, false);});
});
```

I'm at a loss after several hours of attempting everything I could think of. Why doesn't the original in line script work, and why doesn't the callback work in the Chrome App architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into CSP problems, which does not allow inline script or script blocks. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html for details.

You should be able to convert your first attempt by simply creating a `page.js` file, including it via a `script src='page.js'` tag, and put the contents of your script block in it:

```
addLoadListener(addHandlerForLoginButton);
```

Your second versoin didn't work because the `win` parameter to your callback isn't a DOM window but is an `AppWindow`. It has a DOM window attached via the `contentWindow` attribute, see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#type-AppWindow for details.

Lastly, you don't need to list all of those scripts in the `app.background.scripts` field of the manifest, only the background script `background.js`. The others will be loaded as needed when you open your page.

Comment: I read about no inline scripts, but their examples use them, so I thought that the docs were simply behind the times and I might get away with it. When that didn't work, I did comment out the inline and tried the other approach.  Thank you for pointing out that what I thought was a window, isn't. I tried enumerating the properties of the AppWindow and got nothing.  I did have to include one of my .js files in the manifest because that's where the addHandlerForLoginButton is located. I knew I could omit the rest, but I included everything just in case they were needed for some security reason.